# Django: dropdown is populated with ID of ForeignKey, but i would like to populate it with its textual value (not ID)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

In the dropdown I get the `campionato` id, because I'm selecting a ForeignKey. I would like to populate the dropdown with the textual value of the sampled ForeignKey and not with the id. I would like to display the name of the `Campionato` class, which consequently with the ForeignKey is in the `Full_Record` class

**IMPORTANT:** Considering that the two dropdowns are **dependent**, I had to use `campionato` of the `Full_Record` class (and not the one of the `Campionato` class)

[image]

I have read several solutions and similar questions, but they didn't help me. Here is my code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
from  django.contrib import admin

#### BASIC DATA ####
       
#Campionato
class Campionato(models.Model):
    stagione = models.ForeignKey(Stagione, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


#Teams
class Teams(models.Model):
    stagione = models.ForeignKey(Stagione, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campionato = models.ForeignKey(Campionato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    
#### FULL RECORD ####

class Full_Record(models.Model):

    campionato = models.ForeignKey(Campionato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    team_home = ChainedForeignKey(
        Teams,
        related_name='team_home_name',
        chained_field="campionato",
        chained_model_field="campionato",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    
    team_away = ChainedForeignKey(
        Teams,
        related_name='team_away_name',
        chained_field="campionato",
        chained_model_field="campionato",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)

    def partita(self):
        return f"{self.team_home}-{self.team_away}"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.campionato
```

**forms.py**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

<!-- First Combobox -->
<label for="id_campionato">Country</label>

<select name="campionato" id="id_campionato" hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#id_trip" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" hx-trigger="change">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  
  {% for campionato in campionati %}
  <option value="{{ campionato }}">{{ campionato }}</option>
  {% endfor %} 
</select>

<!-- Second Combobox -->
<label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
{% include "trips.html" %}

.......
.......

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Full_Record
import random

def trip_selector(request):
    campionati = Full_Record.objects.values_list('campionato', flat=True).distinct()
    trips = []  # no trips to start with
    return render(request, 'form.html', {"campionati": campionati, "trips": trips})

def trips(request):
    if request.GET.get("campionato"):
        campionato = request.GET.get('campionato')
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=campionato)

    elif request.GET.get("trips"):
        selected_trip_id = int(request.GET.get('trips'))
        selected_trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=selected_trip_id)
        request.session.update({"selected_trip_id": selected_trip_id})
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=selected_trip.campionato)

    return render(request, 'trips.html', {"trips": trips})


def test1(request):
    trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
    sentence = ["The selected trip is ", "Congratulations you have selected the trip ", "You have currently selected travel ", "The currently selected trip is "]
    return f"{random.choice(sentence)} {trip.departure}-{trip.destination}"


def result(request):
    test_print_in_result = test1(request)
    return render(request,"result.html", {"test_print_in_result": test_print_in_result})
```

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why your code isn't using the `__str__` method, but try replacing

```
<option value="{{ campionato }}">{{ campionato }}</option>
```

with

```
<option value="{{ campionato }}">{{ campionato.name }}</option>
```

More generally if you want the option to display something that's derived from the model fields, then

```
<option value="{{ campionato }}">{{ campionato.get_name_label }}</option>
```

where `get_name_label` is a method or property of `Companiato`.

[Update]

The problem must be that `campionati` in the template, which is iterated over to get `campionato`, isn't an iterable of `Campionato` instances. It doesn't have `.name`, so the Django template engine silently ignores the error and substitutes a null string.

This relates to the view code

```
trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=selected_trip.campionato)

return render(request, 'trips.html', {"trips": trips})
```

so `trips`  is an iterable of `Full_Record` instances, so in the template you will need `{{campionato.campionato.name}}`

Which is as confusing as hell because of bad variable name choices.
Suggested changes

```
return render(request, 'trips.html', {"fullrecords": trips})
```

and

```
{% for record in fullrecords %}
    <option value="{{ record }}">{{ record.campionato.name }}</option>
```

if you really are wanting to select `Fullrecord` objects and not Campionato objects. Check this. You might want `value="{{record.campionato}}"`. I don't know the bigger picture so I can't comment further.

Comment: I tested your code (both), but it doesn't work. In both cases I get the dropdwon is empty with nothing inside. Previously there was 1 of the id, now there is nothing: empty. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you

Comment: The reason `__str__` not getting called is `.values_list(…)` in views.py . Replace it with `.all()`, and also in template `<option value="{{ campionato.id }}">{{ campionato }}</option>`.

Comment: @Ezon Zhao It does not work. In views.py, I replaced .values_list with .all. Then I also replaced <option value="{{ championship.id }}">{{ championship }}</option>. I get the BaseManager.all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flat' error as soon as I open the page. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @nigel222 I tried to apply your suggestions,but it doesn't work.In views.py i replaced {"fullrecords": trips}), then in forms I replaced the entire for loop including option. I tested, but the dropdown is empty.I also tried replacing value="{{record.campionato}}", but the dropdown is still empty. 
Either I was wrong to apply them because, or there is something wrong with your answer. P.S: your {{campionato.campionato.name}} was just a confusing critique right? I had to write this too? (I do not believe). Could you review your code better please? Thank you. I think we are close to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I did not get it correctly.
Here is the full, revised version of my answer

```py
# views.py
def trip_selector(request):
    campionati = Full_Record.objects.values(pk=F('campionato__id'), name=F('campionato__name')).distinct()
    trips = []
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'campionati': campionati, 'trips': trips})
```

```html
<!— form.html —>
{% for campionato in campionati %}
<option value="{{ campionato.pk }}">{{ campionato.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

`.values_list('campionato', flat=True)` turns the queryset into a 1-D list, of which elements are just ids of campionato.

`.values(..)` on the other hand turns the queryset into a list of dictionaries, containing specified field-value pairs.

Comment: I DIVIDE THE COMMENT INTO TWO PARTS. PART 1: Your code doesn't work. Using your code, the sampled dropdown is populated correctly, but it is no longer dependent on the second dropdown, because the second dropdown remains empty. Before using your code, when the first dropdown was populated with the id, it was dependent correctly with the second dropdown

Comment: PART 2. Perhaps the reason for your error is that you use championship.name. There is no league.name in the Full_Record class. It only exists in the Championship class, but if I use the Championship class I think then it breaks the dropdown dependency. For that reason, I think, I have to use Full_Record's league. As said in the question, considering that the two dropdowns are dependent, I had to use campionato of Full_Record class (and not that of Campionato class). I think we are close to the solution. Can you review your code please? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What I did so far is just revise the `campionati` queryset. `trips` is set to an empty list, same as in your sample code.

Comment: When you say the two drop-downs are dependent, what does that mean? Will the second drop-down change its options if I alternate the first drop-down? If so, how do you achieve this? It usually require some javascript, but I couldn't find any implementations.

Comment: I divide the comment into two parts. PART 1. Exact. If I select an item in the first dropdown, the items populated in the second dropdown will change accordingly. Currently this works fine in my code. I don't use javascript, but I do use HTMX. Indeed, currently, if in the first dropdown I select id 1, then in the second dropdown I will see items related to that id. The employee dropdown mechanism works correctly. The problem is only that the first dropdown is populated by the id number, and not by the textual value

Comment: PART 2. This is because I am displaying a sample of Full_Record which is a ForeignKey. I can't use name of class Championship, because otherwise I would populate the dropdown correctly, but dependent dropdowns would break, because to be dependent they only use Full_Record. Can you help me?

Comment: Interesting. Did you only replace the for-loop part of the template, and leave the outer <select> tag unchanged? Could check in your browser inspector that the options are rendered correctly? Could you also check in your django development server that a correct request is sent when you changing the 1st select box?